# Telerik RadGrid export to excel gives paper format Letter and I need A4

Tags: asp.net, excel, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-ajax

I have not found where to set this setting. I have really tried, maybe it does not exist.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration option to handle this export formatting when you are using ExcelML export.

Configure the ExportSettings for your [AJAX Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) similar to the following:

```
<ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="true" OpenInNewWindow="true" Excel-Format="ExcelML" />
```

Handle the OnExcelMLWorkBookCreated event, and you can set the papersize with the following property:

```
protected void grid_ExcelMLWorkBookCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelBuilder.GridExcelMLWorkBookCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    e.WorkBook.Worksheets[0].WorksheetOptions.Print.PaperSize = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4;
}
```

Here is a link to the [RadGrid ExcelML Export documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-excelbuilder.html).